# Milling power planes

Tags: pcb-design, ground-plane

I just started sketching a simple PCB for LEDs with integrated drivers, it has large unused spaces and being lightweight is important, so I was considering milling holes in the middle of these empty spaces. Would these cause any unwanted loops or noise problems? Max current would be 60mA per LED and 16 LEDs per board.

Traces positions/width were just to start the sketch and are not final.

[image: teal is milling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case of designs that include high speed (10+ MHz) digital logic or sensitive analog circuits, large [holes or slots](http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/tips-slots.html) do mean that you have to [think about return current paths](http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/split-gnd-plane.html) and bypass to avoid creating large loop areas and resulting EMC trouble.  But for a simple board with LEDs and drivers, even if PWMed, you don't need to worry about that kind of thing.  It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you would get more gain using a thinner than conventional PCB material. Normal boards are usually 0.0625" thick. Use 0.031" board material and cut the weight down by almost half.

Another way to reduce weight is to see if you can get all the traces and pads on one side and eliminate one layer of the copper.

Both of the above approaches will give you a net gain toward your goal without having to incur the expense of milling big holes into your circuit board.

Comment: I already plan to use thinner materials, I'm trying to gain even more weight by milling. Also it is not retangular so I already have to have it milled. The board is mirrored on the other side(LEDs on the same position) so single side is not an option.